# How to return an array of keys after d3.group?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

Following the first example here: https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-group, I group by `sport`:

```
athletes = [
  {name: "Floyd Mayweather", sport: "Boxing", nation: "United States", earnings: 285},
  {name: "Lionel Messi", sport: "Soccer", nation: "Argentina", earnings: 111},
  {name: "Cristiano Ronaldo", sport: "Soccer", nation: "Portugal", earnings: 108},
  {name: "Conor McGregor", sport: "MMA", nation: "Ireland", earnings: 99},
  {name: "Neymar", sport: "Soccer", nation: "Brazil", earnings: 90},
  {name: "LeBron James", sport: "Basketball", nation: "United States",  earnings: 85.5},
  {name: "Roger Federer", sport: "Tennis", nation: "Switzerland", earnings: 77.2},
  {name: "Stephen Curry", sport: "Basketball", nation: "United States", earnings: 76.9},
  {name: "Matt Ryan", sport: "Football", nation: "United States", earnings: 67.3},
  {name: "Matthew Stafford", sport: "Football", nation: "United States", earnings: 59.5}
]

athletesBySport = d3.group(athletes, d => d.sport)
```

Next, I'd like to get a simple array containing the keys (sports). Desired output:

```
['Boxing', 'Soccer', 'MMA', 'Basketball', 'Tennis', 'Football']
```

(order doesn't matter)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`d3.group`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/main/README.md#group) returns a `Map`, and a `Map` has a method [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) which returns a `iterator`. You can get an array out of this `iterator` with `Array.from()` - see below:

```js
const athletes = [
  {name: "Floyd Mayweather", sport: "Boxing", nation: "United States", earnings: 285},
  {name: "Lionel Messi", sport: "Soccer", nation: "Argentina", earnings: 111},
  {name: "Cristiano Ronaldo", sport: "Soccer", nation: "Portugal", earnings: 108},
  {name: "Conor McGregor", sport: "MMA", nation: "Ireland", earnings: 99},
  {name: "Neymar", sport: "Soccer", nation: "Brazil", earnings: 90},
  {name: "LeBron James", sport: "Basketball", nation: "United States",  earnings: 85.5},
  {name: "Roger Federer", sport: "Tennis", nation: "Switzerland", earnings: 77.2},
  {name: "Stephen Curry", sport: "Basketball", nation: "United States", earnings: 76.9},
  {name: "Matt Ryan", sport: "Football", nation: "United States", earnings: 67.3},
  {name: "Matthew Stafford", sport: "Football", nation: "United States", earnings: 59.5}
]

const athletesBySport = d3.group(athletes, d => d.sport)

// Next, I'd like to get a simple array containing the keys (sports). Desired output:
// ['Boxing', 'Soccer', 'MMA', 'Basketball', 'Tennis', 'Football']
const sports = Array.from(athletesBySport.keys());
console.log(sports);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you can explore use of `d3.groups` (note the 's') which instead of a `Map` returns an array of arrays structured with key(s)/ values. Perhaps easier as more familiar array logic can be used e.g.: `athletesBySport.map(pair => pair[0]);`.
Example:

```js
const athletes = [
  {name: "Floyd Mayweather", sport: "Boxing", nation: "United States", earnings: 285},
  {name: "Lionel Messi", sport: "Soccer", nation: "Argentina", earnings: 111},
  {name: "Cristiano Ronaldo", sport: "Soccer", nation: "Portugal", earnings: 108},
  {name: "Conor McGregor", sport: "MMA", nation: "Ireland", earnings: 99},
  {name: "Neymar", sport: "Soccer", nation: "Brazil", earnings: 90},
  {name: "LeBron James", sport: "Basketball", nation: "United States",  earnings: 85.5},
  {name: "Roger Federer", sport: "Tennis", nation: "Switzerland", earnings: 77.2},
  {name: "Stephen Curry", sport: "Basketball", nation: "United States", earnings: 76.9},
  {name: "Matt Ryan", sport: "Football", nation: "United States", earnings: 67.3},
  {name: "Matthew Stafford", sport: "Football", nation: "United States", earnings: 59.5}
]

const athletesBySport = d3.groups(athletes, d => d.sport)

// Next, I'd like to get a simple array containing the keys (sports). Desired output:
// ['Boxing', 'Soccer', 'MMA', 'Basketball', 'Tennis', 'Football']
const sports = athletesBySport.map(pair => pair[0]);
console.log(sports);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```